# Goto folder option with shortcut like in mac

Tags: windows

Do we have an equivalent windows shortcut to go a specific folder in Windows ?

example command + shift + g open the folder path and gives the folder path, it goes the respective folder in mac

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.

In an explorer window, press F4 to move the cursor to the addresbar and hilight it. If you now type in the path you want to go, followed by an enter, the explorer window will navigate to that path.

In addition, you can press the down key to access recent typed in locations.

In addition, you can actually start programs from the address bar, and the programs are started in that location. For example: F4 -> cmd will launch a command prompt in that location, and pressing down will also show the cmd to do it quickly, if it is something you do often.

Comment: Finder has a menu item -> under Go ("Go to Folder…") where we can type a full path.
<br><br>
The command+shift+G keyboard shortcut makes it handy to summon. This short cut works in the file open and save dialog as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

> **`Windows key + R`**

this will open Run window.
In the run window, paste the **`<Folder Path>`** and give enter, this will open a file explorer with the given path.

If you are using windows in mac device (bootcamp etc)

Then windows key equivalent is Command in Apple keyboard[image]

So press

> **`Command + R`**

Comment: We are talking about Mac laptop

Comment: Your question's first line is `"Do we have an equivalent windows shortcut to go a specific folder in Windows ?"`
You yourself has given the shortcut for mac.

Comment: The above doesn't work... I am using Apple Mac Mojave 10.14 version. Not sure about your Apple OS..but it doesn't work

Comment: @OdataDev You are asking for windows shortcut in apple keyboard right ?

Comment: Sorry Nisthanth..It's my mistake..I am having mac laptop..mistakenly put it as Windows laptop..Please forgive..

Comment: Please provide the details for both the laptops so that when anyone refers they will not have confusion